# nested/dynamic handlebars in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Maybe I'm thinking about this the wrong way but let me explain:

I have 16 products and multiple orders. I know that these will be the only 16 products I ever have. (the following code doesn't work)

```
<div ng-repeat="order in orders">
    <span ng-repeat="product in products">{{order.{{product}}}}</span> 
</div>
```

my orders are structured like this:

```
{"date":"5834755","product1":564,"product2":456,etc...
```

I could write it like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="order in orders">
    <span>{{order.product1}}</span>
    <span>{{order.product2}}</span>
    etc...
</div>
```

I am probably overthinking and trying to over simplify my template... What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used a similar notation to print the data of an object and I recommend you do the following:

```
<div ng-repeat="order in orders">
    <span ng-repeat="product in products">{{order[product]}}</span> 
</div>
```

This should work.